# height upon scroll detected too early

Tags: jquery, html, css

UPDATED:
Ok, I have created a fiddle to show what is happening: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmdshelly/s34nj6hp/19/)  There are 3 navs, the first one is static, the second two are supposed to fade in once that page hits the top.  It looks like the second nav seems to work, but they are really both triggering as soon as you start scrolling.  By the time you get to the third page, the nav is already faded in.
~~~~~~~~~
I am trying to fade in a header once the user scrolls past a certain point.  The fadeTo is working, but it is triggering too early (shortly after you start scrolling).  Here is my code:

HTML

```
<header class="third-page">
    <nav class="contact-nav">
        <img src="resources/img/DoveLogo.svg" alt="Inherent Wellbeing Logo" class="nav-logo">
        <ul class="all-nav main-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
     </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.contact-nav {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var topHeight = $('.contact-nav').height();
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= topHeight) {
            $('.contact-nav').fadeTo(1500, 1);
        }
    });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you provide more html code not just the one that will be displayed as you scroll

Comment: make us a jsfiddle please, we don't know enough information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `$('.contact-nav').height()` doesn't give you the offset position of the element, but its height, so that's not the right value to check your `.scrollTop` against.

2) Combine both `.scroll()` functions in one function to reduce processing (since both navbars have to be checked against the current `scrollTop`. So no need for two seperate `$(function () { ... })`s

3) Why use jQuery's `fadeTo()`? (which gets called on every pixel scrolled, which is a lot of processing) Instead use CSS's `transition` for the nav elements, so you only have to toggle the `.show` class on and off.

4) The nav's are set (CSS) to `display:none` which means jQuery can't get their offset position.

I edited your Fiddle (CSS part and JS) and added comments to explain: https://jsfiddle.net/s34nj6hp/21/